# Module with shared state

Tags: asp.net, functional-programming, f#, middleware

I'm currently in middle of writing a ASP.NET Core middleware in F#.
Basically the way I wanted to implement it is that a service does one-time scan of implemented types in given assembly and puts the results in a dictionary, and then the middleware function uses the result of that scan to do some work.

Obviously, I don't want to redo the scanning for each call. I want to do it on application start (initialize the dictionary) and then use it for each call, but I struggle to come up with a solution for it in F#.

In C# I would basically make a stateful class, that contains that dictionary, and then I would have the middleware class use it.

It's basically a shared state between the service and the middleware, but I have no clue on how to approach this problem in F#, even if I were to go outside the functional paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

There may be other concerns that are not clear from your question, but the simplest way to have some shared code with state (which is initialized at some point when the application starts) is to put your code into a `module`. In the module, you can run whatever you need and the F# compiler ensures this is run before you access anything from the module (it is done in a static constructor).

For example, you could add a file `shared.fs` with the following:

```
module Shared

let private things =
    printfn "Doing some initialization..."
    [ "a", 123 ] |> dict

let fetchThing key = 
    things.[key]
```

If you put this as the first file in your project (it has to be *before* other files that refer to it), then you can then call `Shared.fetchThing "a"` from other part of your program - and you'll get the value stored in the dictionary.

Comment: In the past I've seen that this kind of initialization code can run before any exception handler, log system or GUI is up and running. I've had cases where not even some basic stuff in .NET works as expected at that point. I typically only use it for initializing data structures, as shown here, and I take great care not to risk any exceptions being thrown.

Comment: @BentTranberg Yeah, I agree this way of doign things has many limitations - e.g. the fact that it is hard to say when exactly the initialization happens. Without knowing more about OP's exact situation, I think it may be hard to give a better advice. Perhaps a sensible option is to have just one main initialization block that calls `Shared.init ()` to populate the dictionary, once other things are initialized (if there are other things to initialize).